AJAX button doing nothing in Wordpress plugin
I have a simple wordpress plugin to create and delete "Ad campaigns" which are essentially posts in the wordpress database. They submit fine. Problem is, when I try to delete them dynamically using the button in my code the delete button is doing nothing and the POST request isn't sending when I check console. Anyone have any insight on this?
This is my full code for reference
**
PHP Code**
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Game Server Ad Campaigns
Description: A plugin to allow users to add and display advertisement campaigns for game servers.
Version: 1.0
Author: xxxx
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

class GameServerAdCampaigns {

    public function __construct() {
        add_shortcode('campaign_submission_form', array($this, 'campaign_submission_form_shortcode'));
        add_shortcode('campaign_list', array($this, 'campaign_list_shortcode'));
        add_action('init', array($this, 'register_campaign_post_type'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_submit_campaign', array($this, 'submit_campaign'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_campaign', array($this, 'submit_campaign'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_delete_campaign', array($this, 'delete_campaign'));
    }

    public function register_campaign_post_type() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => 'Campaigns',
            'singular_name' => 'Campaign',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Campaign',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Campaign',
            'new_item' => 'New Campaign',
            'all_items' => 'All Campaigns',
            'view_item' => 'View Campaign',
            'search_items' => 'Search Campaigns',
            'not_found' => 'No campaigns found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No campaigns found in Trash',
            'menu_name' => 'Campaigns'
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'campaigns'),
        );

        register_post_type('campaign', $args);
    }

    public function campaign_submission_form_shortcode() {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            return 'You need to be logged in to submit a campaign.';
        }

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="campaign-submission-form">
            <h2>Submit Your Campaign</h2>
            <form id="campaign-form">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="campaign-title" placeholder="Campaign Title" required><br>
                <textarea name="description" id="campaign-description" placeholder="Campaign Description" required></textarea><br>
                <input type="url" name="server_link" id="campaign-server-link" placeholder="Server Link" required><br>
                <input type="number" step="0.10" name="cost_per_hour" id="campaign-cost-per-hour" placeholder="Cost Per Hour ($)" required><br>
                <button type="submit">Submit Campaign</button>
            </form>
            <div id="campaign-result"></div>
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

public function campaign_list_shortcode() {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'campaign',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

    ob_start();
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        ?>
        <div class="campaign-list">
            <h2>Campaigns</h2>
            <ul>
                <?php
                while ($query->have_posts()) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    $server_link = esc_url(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'server_link', true));
                    $cost_per_hour = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cost_per_hour', true);
                    $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
                    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
                    $user_name = $user_info->display_name;
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                        <p>Cost Per Hour: $<?php echo esc_html(number_format($cost_per_hour, 2)); ?></p>
                        <p>Submitted by: <?php echo esc_html($user_name); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php echo $server_link; ?>" target="_blank">Visit Server</a>
                        <?php if (get_current_user_id() == $user_id) : ?>
                            <button class="delete-campaign-button" data-campaign-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Delete</button>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else {
        echo '<p>No campaigns found.</p>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('campaign-script', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null, true);
        wp_localize_script('campaign-script', 'campaign_ajax', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
        wp_enqueue_style('campaign-styles', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
    }

    public function submit_campaign() {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            wp_send_json_error('You need to be logged in to submit a campaign.');
        }

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['title']);
        $description = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['description']);
        $server_link = esc_url_raw($_POST['server_link']);
        $cost_per_hour = floatval($_POST['cost_per_hour']);

        // Validate cost per hour to ensure it's in increments of 0.10
        if ($cost_per_hour <= 0 || fmod($cost_per_hour, 0.10) != 0) {
            wp_send_json_error('Cost per hour must be a positive number and in increments of $0.10.');
        }

        $campaign_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_type' => 'campaign',
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => $description,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => $user_id, // Save the user ID as the post author
        ));

        if ($campaign_id) {
            update_post_meta($campaign_id, 'server_link', $server_link);
            update_post_meta($campaign_id, 'cost_per_hour', $cost_per_hour);
            wp_send_json_success('Campaign submitted successfully.');
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error('There was an error submitting your campaign.');
        }
    }

    public function delete_campaign() {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            wp_send_json_error('You need to be logged in to delete a campaign.');
        }

        $campaign_id = intval($_POST['campaign_id']);
        $campaign = get_post($campaign_id);

        if ($campaign && $campaign->post_type == 'campaign' && $campaign->post_author == get_current_user_id()) {
            if (wp_delete_post($campaign_id, true)) {
                wp_send_json_success('Campaign deleted successfully.');
            } else {
                wp_send_json_error('There was an error deleting the campaign.');
            }
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error('You are not authorized to delete this campaign.');
        }
    }
}

new GameServerAdCampaigns();

Javascript code
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Handle form submission
    $('#campaign-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var title = $('#campaign-title').val();
        var description = $('#campaign-description').val();
        var serverLink = $('#campaign-server-link').val();
        var costPerHour = $('#campaign-cost-per-hour').val();

        console.log('Submitting campaign:', { title, description, serverLink, costPerHour });

        $.post(campaign_ajax.ajax_url, {
            action: 'submit_campaign',
            title: title,
            description: description,
            server_link: serverLink,
            cost_per_hour: costPerHour
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('Submit campaign response:', response);
            if (response.success) {
                $('#campaign-result').html('<p>' + response.data + '</p>');
                $('#campaign-form')[0].reset();
            } else {
                $('#campaign-result').html('<p>' + response.data + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });

    // Handle campaign deletion
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-campaign-button', function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this campaign?')) {
            var button = $(this);
            var campaignId = button.data('campaign-id');

            console.log('Deleting campaign:', { campaignId });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: campaign_ajax.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'delete_campaign',
                    campaign_id: campaignId
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('Delete campaign response:', response);
                    if (response.success) {
                        button.closest('li').remove();
                    } else {
                        alert(response.data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});


Checked console to see if request was sending. Console shows nothing when button clicked. Checked over code multiple times and can't workout why.

Can you create and add a screenshot of what you see and tell us which button does not respond to clicks?

On page load you have a code of
$('#campaign-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    //...
});

However, if this runs before your form is displayed, then #campaign-form does not exist yet when you are to register DOM listeners to it. This could be a fix if this is a problem:
$('body').on('submit', '#campaign-form', function(e) {
    //...
});

